# quicksort for integers, segmentation fault in rand()

Tags: c, srand

I'm writing a quicksort algorithm for integers and I get a strange segfault error in srand functions. Here is the code from sort.h:

```
int distributePivot (int *a, int left, int pivot, int right) {
    int i, j;
    if (pivot != right)
        swapInt(&pivot, &right);
    i = left;
    j = right - 1;
    while (i < j) {
        while (i < j && a[i] <= a[right])
            i++;
        while (j > i && a[j] >= a[right])
            j--;
        if (i < j)
            swapInt(&a[i], &a[j]);
    }
    if (i < right)
        swapInt(&a[i], &a[right]);
    return i;
}

void intArrayQuickSort (int *a, int left, int right) {
    int pivot;
    if (left < right) {
            pivot = rand() % (right - left +1) + left;
        pivot = distributePivot(a, left, pivot, right);
        intArrayQuickSort (a, left, pivot -1);
        intArrayQuickSort (a, pivot, right);
    }
}
```

And here is the calling from sort-test.c:

```
    srand(time(NULL));
    intArrayQuickSort(temp, 0, n - 1);
```

Where `temp` is a pointer to integer.

And here is the error I get when i execute it in gdb:

```
    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0x00007ffff77e9884 in rand () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Can you please help me?

Thank you very much.

EDIT: This is the swapInt function:

```
void swapInt (int *a, int *b) {
    int aux = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = aux;
}
```

Comment: It is likely that you are overwriting a buffer somewhere; have you run this under Valgrind?

Comment: Does the problem go away if you choose a pivot without using rand() ?

Comment: Can we see the `swapInt` function?

Comment: In `distributePivot`, instead of `swapInt(&pivot, &right);` you need `swapInt(&a[pivot], &a[right]);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the program logic.
E.g.
in main
array = [1,2]
call intArrayQuickSort(array, 0, 1);// a:array, left:0, right:1
in intArrayQuickSort
pivot = 1 //provisional result of `rand() % (right - left +1) + left;`
call distributePivot(a, 0, 1, 1)
in distributePivot
not swap (pivot, right) because pivot == righit
i = 0  //left
j = 0  //right - 1
not execute while block because i == j
execute swap (a[i],a[right]) because i < right // 0 < 1
//a = [2, 1]  //!!NG
return 0
//Already illegal state
in intArrayQuickSort
pivot = 0 ;//from return value : 0
call intArrayQuickSort (a, 0, -1);//left:0, pivot -1 :-1
no operation return
call intArrayQuickSort (a, 1,  1);//pivot + 1:1, right : 1
no operation return
in main
result:a = [2, 1] //NG!

Comment: There is a need to review the logic of the program itself.

Comment: Thanks, I already found that error once I solved the other one. Now my functions works.

Comment: @Zagorax - This story is after change to `intArrayQuickSort (a, pivot + 1, right);`. your program logic is still wrong.

Comment: @Zagorax - If you have already solved the problem if you want to delete the question. Alternatively, please edit the code of the question if an error has occurred that fix still on.

Comment: @BLUEPRIX - Oh damn. You were right. I had 50% of chance to fail when I have only two elements (and I always have because of the recursion). I fixed it. Thank you very much. Should I modify the code in the question or it's enough to mark your as correct answer?

Comment: I do not know that whether it is correct because i have not seen the program that was eventually corrected.

Comment: I changed the condition for the main while from `i < j` to `i <= j`, in this way also with two values, i will be incremented to the value of right and so there will be no swap between i and right at the end (and neither between i and j because i > j).

Comment: @Zagorax - if you change `while(i<j)` to `while(i<=j)` , perhaps, it is not what this program properly.

Comment: I think that will not be able to exit the loop if 'j' and 'i' are equal.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12347/discussion-between-zagorax-and-bluepixy)

Comment: @Zagorax - We're sorry, but I must sleep soon.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've found a solution, but I don't know why it works.
The second recursive call should be:

```
intArrayQuickSort (a, pivot + 1, right);
```

It makes sense for the algorithm, but I can't understand why the error is with rand(). Any explanation?

Comment: It might be a stack overflow: recurring too deeply and so the function call into `rand` runs off the end of the stack and attempts to access memory illegally, hence segfault (you could try putting any function before the `rand` and see if that causes the same problem in the new function).

Comment: @Zagorax - The program is also incorrect to make this change. you can see the my answers

Comment: @dbaupp - But in the case, it's not the rand() functions that generate the stack overflow but some assignment o similar outside the range.

Answer (score 0):

I think a modified version of

```
int distributePivot (int *a, int left, int pivot, int right) {
    int i, j;
    if (pivot != right)
        swapInt(&a[pivot], &a[right]);
    i = left;
    j = right - 1;
    while (1) {
        while (i < right && a[i] < a[right])
            i++;
        while (left <= j && a[j] >= a[right])
            j--;
        if (i < j)
            swapInt(&a[i], &a[j]);
        else
            break;
    }
    if(i < right)
        swapInt(&a[i], &a[right]);
    return i;
}
void intArrayQuickSort (int *a, int left, int right) {
    int pivot;
    if (left < right) {
        pivot = rand() % (right - left +1) + left ;
        pivot = distributePivot(a, left, pivot, right);
        intArrayQuickSort (a, left, pivot - 1);
        intArrayQuickSort (a, pivot + 1, right);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't like that break inside the while. Your solution seems to work, but my teacher always says to avoid this. Have a look to the one I posted on the chat. That one works and does the same.

Comment: @Zagorax - I chose to break because it was unpleasant to have duplicate `i < j`. Good to do it like you want to do.

Answer (score -1):

```
pivot = rand() % (right - left +1) + left;
```

Should be:

```
pivot = left + rand() % (right - left +1);
```

Or maybe even:

```
pivot = left +1 + rand() % (right - left);
```

Comment: Oops, me neither. Maybe that's why I added the third?

Comment: Actually I got the same error with all of your possibility. Why they should be different from mine?

Comment: Well, maybe it was wrong. In your case, I would do some printf() debugging. It is probably an off-by-one, somewhere. BTW: in most cases it helps if you use only unsigned types for indexing purposes. (when wrapped, unsigned will become 0xfffffffffffff, which will segfault at the first occation, before doing any real damage)